# My menu on mobile isn't working on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm working on websites for client but I got a problem with responsivity of menu. When you open site with Safari and use width of mobile you can't access the menu after clicking the hamburger in right top corner.

Here is html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden"> <label for="nav"  class="link burger"><i></i><i></i><i></i></label>
<div  class="menu">
  <ul class="menu_ul">
   <li><a class="link fir" id="act">o nás</a></li>
   <li><a class="link sec">rezervace a ceník</a></li>
   <li><a class="link thr">dárkový poukaz</a></li>
   <li><a class="link fou">časté dotazy</a></li>
   <li><a class="link fiv">kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And here CSS:

```
#nav:checked ~ .menu {

  z-index: 9990;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";

}

#nav:checked ~ .menu ul li a {

  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;

  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);

}
```

**Here you can finde the website http://stinohra.com**

Comment: Try removing the width and height from the `burger`

Comment: @David now it can be clicked on Safari but menu still isnt showing up.